# How to retrieve value for a fixed key from multiple yaml files (each yaml file having different schema)?

Tags: java, yaml, pyyaml, snakeyaml

I have following type of YAML files in my system. from each yaml file, I wanted to retrieve the value corresponding to **sql** key. this key can appear more than once or does nor appear at all in the yaml files. all of these yaml files may not have same structures.

Some information about yaml files -

1. All yaml files have **mainComponent** and sql key will be there in this component only.
2. All yaml files have **secondaryComponent** at same level as main component.
3. Just before **sql** key, we have **type: executeSQL** in the same component.
4. Queries can be multiline also(see example 3).

example 1 -

```
mainComponent:
  basic:
    individual:
    - sedan
    groups:
    - normal
    - Premium
  user:
    local: john snow
    outsider: virat kohli
  mySqlComponent:
    name: mySqlComponent
    type: executeSQL
    sql: select name, salary from employee
secondryComponent:
  Mod:
    permissions:
      test: true
    inheritance:
    - Premium
  default:
    permissions: abc
    inheritance: xyz
```

here, I want to extract **sql: select name, salary from employee**.

example 2 -

```
mainComponent:
  basic:
    individual:
    - sedan
    groups:
    - normal
    - Premium
  group:
    you: john 
    me: snow
  yourSqlComponent:
    name: yourSqlComponent
    type: executeSQL
    sql: select name, salary from xyz
  ourSqlComponent:
    name: ourSqlComponent
    type: executeSQL
    sql: select name, salary from zbc
secondryComponent:
  God:
    permissions:
      test: true
    inheritance:
    - Premium
  default:
    permissions: abc
    inheritance: xyz
```

here, I want to extract **sql: select name, salary from xyz** and **sql: select name, salary from zbc**

example 3 -

```
mainComponent:
  basic:
    individual:
    - sedan
    groups:
    - normal
    - Premium
  group:
    you: john 
    me: snow
  multilineSqlComponent:
    name: yourSqlComponent
    type: executeSQL
    sql: |-
      select name, salary 
      from xyz
      where id = 1

secondryComponent:
  God:
    permissions:
      test: true
    inheritance:
    - Premium
  default:
    permissions: abc
    inheritance: xyz
```

there can be multiline query, the will appear like as shown above.
here, I want to extract           **select name, salary
from xyz
where id = 1**

example 4 -

```
mainComponent:
  basic:
    individual:
    - sedan
    groups:
    - normal
    - Premium
  user:
    local: john snow
    outsider: virat kohli
secondryComponent:
  Mod:
    permissions:
      test: true
    inheritance:
    - Premium
  default:
    permissions: abc
    inheritance: xyz
```

nothing to extract here as there is **no sql key**.

Also, I have one **key-value** pair which is **type: executeSQL** that will definitely be present just before **sql** key and **under the same component**. can this information be used to get the value corresponding **sql** key ? how can I extract this?

Comment: Could you briefly explain the desired output and its format by providing an example to your inputs? You want to iterate the `.yaml` and find the entry `sql: query`. Is it guaranteed that every `.yaml` shall contain exactly one such entry?

Comment: If you know both the key and the value, what do you want to fetch? You will always get a pair of the strings `"sql"` and `"query"`. Is `query` intended to be a placeholder and what you actually want to do is to fetch all values from mappings inside the YAML which have the key `sql`? Moreover, your second example is not valid YAML – duplicate mapping keys like `authentication` are not allowed.

Comment: edited and added examples, please have a look at it. please ask if you have any more question.

Comment: The problem with YAML *parsing* libraries (https://yaml.org/) is that they are only that - *parsers*. What you're looking for are some *querying* capabilities, much like XPATH for XML files.

Comment: No, I am just looking to fetch a value corresponding to a key and In my case, name of key is sql.

Comment: @akashPatel Yeah, but you don't know the location of the key(s) in advance.

Comment: Yeah, that is what my question is, how to get the value when we dont know the key postion. for now, I am parsing yaml using bufferedReader.